# Use Logstash to parse million logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to be able to parse a million JSON files (static and not being written to by any process) and send to elasticsearch using [ELK](http://elasticsearch.org/). However I run into an error:

```
failed to open /opt/data/input/20140622022503@18312f68.json: Permission denied -
```

It seems logstash is tailing all the files it's opened and therefore can't open anymore. I want to be able to parse these files and have logstash forget them. No need to "tail" them. Is this possible? I see a JIRA opened for this at https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1929. Does anyone else face this problem? Has this been solved or is it an open issue?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. [tag:elki] is not elasticsearch.

Comment: Sorry, was probably a typo. I meant "ELK"

Comment: if the file permissions are set right, it seems like you are hitting a bug/limitation of some sort.  Unless you want to try debuging it yourself, your best bet is to work around the problem.  One possible solution is to cat together all of your .json files into one large log file and then have Logstash process that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error you gave makes it look like the user logstash is running as doesn't have permissions to read the files matching the pattern you are looking for. Or, maybe they don't have access while the file is being written (for a brief moment in time).

Comment: That's what it looks like, but that isn't it. Permissions are all good. The files aren't being written to. They are static and unchanging, untouched by any other process. Edited original Q to say so.

Comment: Either it's the worst error message ever written, or @James is right about permissions.  Don't forget the directory permissions all the way down.

Comment: Yep it's granted from the parent folder on down. `chmod 777 -R <parent dir>`